# How to solve decibels?

Tags: decibel

If  a   microphone  has an  output  voltage of  1.45mV  @   1   Pa  and a   microphone  preamplifier    adds    50dB    of  gain,   what    would   the voltage at  the output  of  the mic pre be, assuming    the pressure    applied to  the diaphragm   never   changes?

Comment: What have you tried?  Do you know what 50 dB is as a ratio?  Do you know what it is a ratio of?  We don't accept unattempted homework problems here, so you'll need to do at least some of this yourself.

Comment: Zero. If the pressure never changes there is no sound.

Comment: Chris Stratton, it's not a homework problem.